# LiveWire Data Binding Problem. (Uncaught ReferenceError: Livewire is not defined)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm new to LiveWire. I think I did everything right. (According to the documentation.)
Why am I not getting interaction?
Thanks..

--- welcome.blade ---

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Livewire</title>
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
    @livewire('hello-world')

    @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>
```

--- Controller ---

```html
class HelloWorld extends Component
{
    public $name = 'Ugur';
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.hello-world');
    }
}
```

--- hello-world.blade ---

```html
<div>
    <input wire:model="name" type="text">

    Hello {{ $name }}
</div>
```

[When the input value changes, the value on the side does not change.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnLbM.png)

Comment: Hey. are you sure livewire is installed correctly? try running `composer require livewire/livewire` again to make sure it is installed correctly.

Other than that, I'm not sure what the problem is. I can't see anything wrong with the code.

maybe open up the network tab in your browser and check if there are outgoing livewire ajax requests to the backend at all. try using the alternative syntax to include the assets `<livewire:styles />` and `<livewire:scripts />`. include any errors you have if any in the console or in the laravel logs.

Comment: LiveWire is correctly installed. I change to alternative syntax. There is an error in the network tab.

This line is showing error. "window.livewire = new Livewire();"

Comment: Error title is "(index):46 
        
       Uncaught ReferenceError: Livewire is not defined"

Comment: That probably means livewire is not installed correctly. try installing livewire in a fresh app following this URL: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/installation
also check this url, might be the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72327068/uncaught-referenceerror-livewire-is-not-defined-using-laravel-8

Comment: SOLVED! - I changed .env APP_URL=http:/localhost TO-> APP_URL=http://localhost/livewire/public
and
changed config/livewire.php under 'asset_url' => null, TO-> 'asset_url' => env('APP_URL'),

Comment: perfect. please post what you did in an answer and accept it so it helps other users that come across the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

I changed;

.env

```html
APP_URL=http:/localhost //TO--> APP_URL=localhost/[project_name]/public
```

and

config/livewire.php

```html
'asset_url' => null, //TO--> 'asset_url' => env('APP_URL'),
```

[Source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/uncaught-referenceerror-livewire-is-not-defined?page=1&replyId=718992)